# Not sure what the where clause means in a function declaration

Tags: c#

I'm doing some Pluralsight training. The instructor specified several function declarations in an interface, one of which looks like this:

```
void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;
```

So generics are being used, the data type is of type "T", it's declaring a parameter named "entity" which is of type T. What I don't understand if the clause:

"where T : class"

What does that mean?

Comment: [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a generic constraint.  It means that the type of T must be a class.

Answer (score 1):

it is a constraint which says your `T` should be a `reference Type`.

From MSDN: [`where T : class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

> The type argument must be a **reference** type; this applies also to any
>   **class**, **interface**, **delegate**, or **array** type.

Answer (score 1):

It's ensuring that the generic type T is of type class.

So as an example `yourClass.Add<int>(2)` would show a compile time error because int is not a class/reference type.